# Concatenate a column from data.frame elements of a list

Tags: r

I am looking for an idiomatic way to join a column, say named 'x', which exists in every data.frame element of a list. I came up with a solution with two steps by using `lapply` and `Reduce`. The second attempt trying to use only `Reduce` failed. Can I actually use only `Reduce` with one anonymous function to do this?

```
#data
xs <- replicate(5, data.frame(x=sample(letters, 10, T), y =runif(10)), simplify = FALSE)
# This works, but may be still unnecessarily long
otmap = lapply(xs, function(df) df$x)
jotm = Reduce(c, otmap)
# This does not count as another solution:
jotm = Reduce(c, lapply(xs, function(df) df$x))

# Try to use only Reduce function. This produces an error
jotr =Reduce(function(a,b){c(a$x,b$x)}, xs)
# Error in a$x : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `unlist` after extracting the 'x' column

```
unlist(lapply(xs, `[[`, 'x'))
#[1] b y y i z o q w p d f f z b h m c u f s j e i v y b w j n q e w i r h p z q f x a b v z e x l c q f
#Levels: b d i o p q w y z c f h m s u e j n v r x a l
```

Comment: I used wrong word, I meant 'concatenate' when I wrote 'join' in the title. The final output should be only a vector of the same type as 'x' column

Comment: @biocyberman Do you need `as.character(unlist(lapply(xs, `[[`, 'x')))`  If you need the `factor` class, remove the `as.character`

Comment: I get the idea, but still get this error:Error: unexpected '[[' in "lapply(xs, [["

Comment: @biocyberman I used only your example and did not get any error

Comment: I did forget the quotes. Thank you @akrun. I am still curious if we can use Reduce function for this purpose.